# Converting RGB to HSV in macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I have the following code to convert RGB to HSV. This uses UIColor which is part of the UIKit. UIKit is not available in macOS. What is the alternative to do this in macOS?

```
func getHue(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> CGFloat 
{
    let color = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
    var hue: CGFloat = 0
    color.getHue(&hue, saturation: nil, brightness: nil, alpha: nil)
    return hue
}
```

Comment: https://kirb.me/2018/06/07/iosmac-research.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In macOS, use `NSColor` instead `UIColor`.

```
func getHue(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let color = NSColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
    var hue: CGFloat = 0
    color.getHue(&hue, saturation: nil, brightness: nil, alpha: nil)
    return hue
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that you need to import `AppKit` to use `NSColor`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`NSColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor) on macOS instead of `UIColor`. The two are similar, though `NSColor` allows for better color management, should you need it. It includes a similar [`getHue(_, saturation, brightness, alpha)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1534060-gethue) method.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this a bit differently:

```
import AppKit

extension NSColor {
    var hsba: (hue: CGFloat, saturation: CGFloat, brightness: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        var hue: CGFloat = 0
        var saturation: CGFloat = 0
        var brightness: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        self.getHue(
            &hue,
            saturation: &saturation,
            brightness: &brightness,
            alpha: &alpha
        )
        return (hue, saturation, brightness, alpha)
    }
}
```

This lets you easily access not just the hue, but the satuation, brightness and alpha as well. And it doesn't require you manually provide 3 seperate rgb components. You can just call it on any existing `NSColor` instance. You might initialize one using rgb components, but you could also use any other other `NSColor` instance, such as one returned by another API, or one of the static value like `NSColor.blue`).

```
print(NSColor.green.hsba.hue)
```